# one class classification with keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-processing, keras, classification

I am trying to build a model to detect whether the input image is something or not(For example, dog or not). I'm coding with keras, but the accuracy is terrible. Do you have any idea to tune this correctly? Or should I use other tools other than keras for one class classification problem? Thank you so much in advance.

Here's the code and the output I've wrote so far.

```
train_dir = './path/to/train_dir'
vali_dir = './path/to/validation_dir'

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1./255,
    rotation_range=40,
    width_shift_range=0.2,
    height_shift_range=0.2,
    shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=False)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        train_dir, 
        target_size=(150, 150), 
        batch_size=20,
        class_mode='binary')

vali_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

vali_generator = vali_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        vali_dir,
        target_size=(150, 150),
        batch_size=20,
        class_mode='binary')

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(16, 3, activation='relu', input_shape=(150, 150, 3)))
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=2))
model.add(Conv2D(32, 3, activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=2))
model.add(Conv2D(64, 3, activation='relu'))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu'))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(1024, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(
        loss='binary_crossentropy',
        optimizer=RMSprop(lr=0.003),
        metrics=['acc']
)

history = model.fit_generator(
        train_generator,
        steps_per_epoch=100,
        epochs=8,
        verbose=2,
        validation_data=vali_generator,
        validation_steps=20
)
```

Output:

```
Found 3379 images belonging to 2 classes.
Found 607 images belonging to 2 classes.
Epoch 1/8
 - 136s - loss: 7.6617 - acc: 0.5158 - val_loss: 10.5220 - val_acc: 0.3400
Epoch 2/8
 - 124s - loss: 7.7837 - acc: 0.5118 - val_loss: 10.5220 - val_acc: 0.3400
.......and this is just terrible.
```

Comment: You seemingly trained only for a two epochs, so I wouldn't expect it to have higher accuracy there. Other things to consider are: Have you tried playing with the hyperparameters? Also, have you analyzed your data (imbalanced distribution of dog/non-dog pictures)?

Comment: @DocDriven thanks for your comment. sorry actually I've trained for 8 epochs but the rest was just as terrible as the first two so I just omitted it. there was seemingly no imbalance. I'll try hyperparameters.

Comment: This is not a classification problem but rather is an object detection problem. There are heaps of documentation about how to implement this online. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to change and tune the parameter and the training data but I didn't get a desirable result. I came across with one class classification using `Isolation forest`. This is known as novelty detection, and after I used it, it performs outstandingly. Thanks for those who advised me in the comments, and I'm sorry to answer on my own.

Comment: hi, I'm having the same issue. could you please provide more info?

Comment: Hi @Franva, did you figure it out?

Comment: @AnshumanKumar I ended up using 2 classes, one class for the thing you are interested in e.g. in my case it's the dogs, and one class for everything else. I know there should be other solutions e.g. anomaly detection, but I haven't tried that. Let me know if you managed to get it working :)

Answer (score 2):

Isolation forest is a good algorithm for anomaly detection, if there is no dependencies among the input features. However, if your input is a time series signal or image, it is better to use methods like RNN or CNN.

I have recently come across an anomaly detection model named one class CNN. It is working great if your input is image or time series signal. Here is a link to their github:

https://github.com/raghavchalapathy/oc-nn

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there is a problem with class labels - are they related to data correctly? You can check it or post ImageDataGenerator code

Comment: the images are labeled according to the name of the directory. In my case, I have 'correct' file and 'wrong' file. I checked the labels with `ImageDataGenerator.class_indices` and it seems like it ok here.

Comment: I had a similar errors. If accuracy don't change during several epochs (I mean, the validation shows the _same_ numbers) classifier predicts single class during validation and ignores other in my case. I.e. if 30% "posititve" samples in your dataset, and your classifier always predicts "positive", classifier's validation accuracy equals 0.3. There were errors with data labelling in my case, and next time just poor data. So classifier couldn't learn on it.

Answer (score 1):

There is a big difference between train accuracy and validation accuracy even from the first epoch.
To me it looks like an overtraining problem. So you should give you network some more regularization. Like more Dropoutlayers or `kernel_regularizer` inside you convolution layers.