# One class classification using Keras and Python

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, classification, conv-neural-network

### Intro and questions:

I'm trying to make a one-class classification convolutional neural network. By one-class I mean I have one image dataset containing about 200 images of Nicolas Cage. By one class classification I mean look at an image and predict 1 if Nicolas Cage is contained in this image and predict 0 Nicolas Cage is not contained in the image.

I’m a definitely a machine learning/deep learning beginner so I was hoping someone with some more knowledge and experience could help guide me in the right direction. Here are my issues and questions right now. My network is performing terribly. I’ve tried making a few predictions with images of Nicolas Cage and it predicts 0 every single time.

- Should I collect more data for this to work? I’m performing data augmentations with a small dataset of 207 images. I was hoping the data augmentations would help the network generalize but I think I was wrong
- Should I try tweaking the amount of epochs, step per epoch, val steps, or the optimization algorithm I’m using for gradient descent? I’m using Adam but I was thinking maybe I should try stochastic gradient descent with different learning rates?
- Should I add more convolution or dense layers to help my network better generalize and learn?
- Should I just stop trying to do one class classification and go to normal binary classification because using a neural network with one class classification is not very feasible? I saw this post here [one class classification with keras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51874969/one-class-classification-with-keras) and it seems like the OP ended up using an isolation forest. So I guess I could try using some convolutional layers and feed into an isolation forest or an SVM? I could not find a lot of info or tutorials about people using isolation forests with one-class image classification.

---

### Dataset:

Here is a screenshot of what my dataset looks like that I’ve collected use a package called google-images-download. It contains about 200 images of Nicolas Cage. I did two searches to download 500 images. After manually cleaning the images I was down to 200 quality pictures of Nic Cage.
[Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c3KKo.png)

---

### The imports and model:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D
from keras.layers import MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Flatten
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import Dropout
from keras.layers import Activation

classifier = Sequential()

classifier.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape = (200, 200, 3), activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))

classifier.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

classifier.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

classifier.add(Flatten())

classifier.add(Dense(units = 64, activation = 'relu'))

classifier.add(Dropout(0.5))

# output layer
classifier.add(Dense(1))
classifier.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
```

---

### Compiling and image augmentation

```
classifier.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])


from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255,
                                   shear_range = 0.2,
                                   zoom_range = 0.2,
                                   horizontal_flip = True)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)

training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory('/Users/ginja/Desktop/Code/Nic_Cage/Small_Dataset/train/',
                                                 target_size = (200, 200),
                                                 batch_size = 32,
                                                 class_mode = "binary")

test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory('/Users/ginja/Desktop/Code/Nic_Cage/Small_Dataset/test/',
                                            target_size = (200, 200),
                                            batch_size = 32,
                                            class_mode = "binary")
```

---

#### Fitting the model

```
history = classifier.fit_generator(training_set,
                         steps_per_epoch = 1000,
                         epochs = 25,
                         validation_data = test_set,
                         validation_steps = 500)

Epoch 1/25
1000/1000 [==============================] - 1395s 1s/step - loss: 0.0012 - acc: 0.9994 - val_loss: 1.0000e-07 - val_acc: 1.0000
Epoch 2/25
1000/1000 [==============================] - 1350s 1s/step - loss: 1.0000e-07 - acc: 1.0000 - val_loss: 1.0000e-07 - val_acc: 1.0000
Epoch 3/25
1000/1000 [==============================] - 1398s 1s/step - loss: 1.0000e-07 - acc: 1.0000 - val_loss: 1.0000e-07 - val_acc: 1.0000
Epoch 4/25
1000/1000 [==============================] - 1342s 1s/step - loss: 1.0000e-07 - acc: 1.0000 - val_loss: 1.0000e-07 - val_acc: 1.0000
Epoch 5/25
1000/1000 [==============================] - 1327s 1s/step - loss: 1.0000e-07 - acc: 1.0000 - val_loss: 1.0000e-07 - val_acc: 1.0000
Epoch 6/25
1000/1000 [==============================] - 1329s 1s/step - loss: 1.0000e-07 - acc: 1.0000 - val_loss: 1.0000e-07 - val_acc: 1.0000
.
.
.
```

The model looks like it converges to a loss value of 1.0000e-07 as this doesn't change for the rest of the epochs

---

### Training and Test accuracy plotted

[Training and Test accuracy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d5smF.png)

### Training and Test loss plotted

[Training and Test loss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LyotR.png)

---

### Making the prediction

```
from keras.preprocessing import image
import numpy as np 

test_image = image.load_img('/Users/ginja/Desktop/Code/Nic_Cage/nic_cage_predict_1.png', target_size = (200, 200))
#test_image.show()
test_image = image.img_to_array(test_image)
test_image = np.expand_dims(test_image, axis = 0)
result = classifier.predict(test_image)
training_set.class_indices
if result[0][0] == 1:
    prediction = 'This is Nicolas Cage'
else:
    prediction = 'This is not Nicolas Cage'

print(prediction)
```

We get 'This is not Nicolas Cage' every single time for the prediction.
I appreciate anyone that takes the time to even read through this and I appreciate any help on any part of this.

Comment: Its not one class classification. It's binary classification How many images you have has "Nicolas Cage" and how many images you have doesn't have Nicolas Cage? basically how many images you have for 1 & 0 ?

Comment: You cannot train a model with samples of only one class, the minimum number of classes is two, so you need samples of "not nicolas cage".

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro So would this would work if I just gathered random images from google images that were "not nicolas cage" and then had the images of nicloas cage. My intuition is that the "not nicolas cage" image set would be too broad and then the network would have a hard time generalizing.

Comment: @venkatakrishnan Yeah I think that's my issue I only image set for 1 and not 0. So 1 representing the Nicolas Cage class.

Comment: Yes. try some random set of images as the not Nicolas cage. and in your final prediction set a threshold on the probability to make it absolutely right

Comment: @venkatakrishnan Will try this now. Thank for your help. One final question, is there a recommended threshold to start out with or is that something I will have to play around with and find the sweet spot on the probability threshold?

Comment: usually anything above .8 is good. but you might have to try around with your model.

Comment: @venkatakrishnan Additional question, is there a way to specify which class is the "1" class and which class is the "0" class in Keras? For example, I want my model to output a "1" if it thinks a picture is Nic Cage and "0" if it thinks it's not nic cage but right now it's outputting 0 for Nic cage and 1 for Not Nic Cage. Thanks for any help!

Comment: @DrewScatterday yes. possible. Basically keep images in 2 folders. 1 -> having all the photos with Nic Cage, 0 -> all the photos without Nic Cage. 

Then use flow from directory. It will be fine.

Comment: @venkatakrishnan Thanks so much for the help, I figured it out. ```flow_from_directory``` reads the folders alphanumerically and I had my folders out of order

Comment: great . happy learning :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If anyone finds this from google I figured it out. I did a couple of things:

1. I added a dataset of random images to my train and test folders. I basically added a "0" class. These images were labeled as "not_nicolas" I downloaded the same amount of images I had in the first dataset which was about 200 images. So I had 200 images of Nicolas Cage and 200 images of random stuff. The random pictures were generated at this link https://picsum.photos/200/200/?random I just used a python script to generate 200 images. Make sure when you use `flow_from_directory` it reads the folders in alphanumeric order. So the first folder in the directory will be class "0". Took me way too long to figure that out.

```
path = "/Users/ginja/Desktop/Code/Nic_Cage/Random_images"

for i in range(200):
    url = "https://picsum.photos/200/200/?random"
    response = requests.get(url)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        file_name = 'not_nicolas_{}.jpg'.format(i)
        file_path = path + "/" + file_name
        with open(file_path, 'wb') as f:
            print("saving: " + file_name)
            f.write(response.content)
```

2. I changed the optimizer to Stochastic Gradient Descent instead of Adam.
3. I added `shuffle = True` as a parameter in the flow_from_directory to shuffle our images to allow our network to generalize better

   I now have a training accuracy of 99% and a Test accuracy of 91% and I am able to predict images of Nicolas Cage successfully!

Comment: shuffle is True by default

Answer (score 7):

Everyone leans towards a binary classification approach. This may be a solution but removes the fundamental design objective which may be to solve it with a one class classifier.
Depending on what you want to achieve with a one-class classifier it can be an ill-conditioned problem.
In my experience, your last point often applies.

As mentioned in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1801.05365.pdf:

> In  the  classical multiple-class   classification,   features   are   learned   with   the objective of maximizing inter-class distances between classes and minimizing intra-class variances within classes [2]. How-ever, in the absence of multiple classes such a discriminative approach is not possible.

It yields a trivial solution. The reason why is explained a bit later:

> The reason  why  this  approach  ends  up  yielding  a  trivial  solution is  due  to  the  absence  of  a  regularizing  term  in  the  loss function  that  takes  into  account  the  discriminative  ability  of the network. For example, since all class labels are identical, a zero loss can be obtained by making all weights equal to zero. It is true that this is a valid solution in the closed world where onlynormal chairobjects exist. But such a network has zero discriminative ability whenabnormal chairobjects appear

Note that the description here is made with regards to attempting to use one class classifiers to solve for different classes. One other useful objective of one class classifiers is to detect anomaly in e.g. factory operation signals. This is what I am currently working on. In such cases, having knowledge regarding the various damage states is very hard to obtain. It would be ridiculous to break a machine just to see how it operates when broken so that a decent multinomial classifier can be made. One solution to the problem is described in the following: https://arxiv.org/abs/1912.12502. Note that in this paper, because of the stochastic similarity of the classes, the descriminative capacity of classes is achieved as well.

I found that by following the guidelines described and specially, removing the last activation function, I got my one-class classifier working and the acuraccy did not give 0 values. Note that in your case you may also want to remove to binary-cross entropy since that requires binary inputs to make sense (use RMSE).

This method should also work for your case. In that case the network would be capable of determining which photos are numerically further away from the training photo class. In my experience however, it is likely still a hard problem to solve due to the variance contained in the pictures e.g. different background, angles, etc... To that end, the problem I am solving is much easier as there is much more similarity between operating conditions of the same condition stage. To put that into analogy, in my case the training class is more like the same picture with different noise levels and only slight movements of objects.

Answer (score 4):

**Treating your problem as supervised problem:**

You are solving a face recognition problem. Your problem is binary classification problem if you want to distinguish between "Nicolas Cage" or any other random image. For binary classification you need to have a class with 0 label or not "Nicolas Cage" class.

If I take a very famous example then it is Hotdog-Not-Hotdog problem (Silicon Valley). 
These links might help you.

https://towardsdatascience.com/building-the-hotdog-not-hotdog-classifier-from-hbos-silicon-valley-c0cb2317711f

https://github.com/J-Yash/Hotdog-Not-Hotdog/blob/master/Hotdog_classifier_transfer_learning.ipynb

**Treating your problem as Unsupervised problem:**

In this you can represent your image into an embedding vector. Pass your Nicolas Cage image into a pre-trained facenet that will give you face embedding and plot that embedding to see the relation between every image.

https://paperswithcode.com/paper/facenet-a-unified-embedding-for-face

Comment: I ended up figuring it out, thank you for your help and your time!